# How can I implement a list view with long items?

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

I Implemented a `ExpandableListView`. But its Items are very long and it doesn't appear in the screen!

I used `HorizantalScrollView` to solve this problem. But it resized to minimal with(header with).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lstUploadList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: can you please paste the code of layout file.

Answer (score 0):

You donot need horizontal scroll view for that what you need is to set the layout_height="wrap_content" .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lstUploadList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ExpandableListView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

or if you want to scroll the layout horizontally than you have to set the width of horizontal layout to wrap_content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lstUploadList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```